# How can I get Explorer Search to search for #?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I get Explorer Search to find all and only files containing the character **#** ?

Here:

[image]

simply entering **#** gives a false result:

[image]

Likewise, entering **"#"** .

EDIT: Folder Options, 'Find partial matches' is checkmarked and 'Use natural language search' is not.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. This is about #. That is about ?.

Comment: Did you try the method suggested in the other post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in Windows 7.

```
"*#*"
```

[image: Windows Search on #]

If you don't like having to enter all those extra characters, a free program called [Everything Search](http://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/) will search for # easily:

[image: Everything # Search Results]

Comment: Works here too: http://i.imgur.com/uKmweor.png Thanks.

Comment: You are right @ChrisJJ. I was overzealous in having this question marked as a duplicate. Indeed, this is a separate question. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go into the setting for search in "Folder Options", and make sure that "Find Partial Matches" is checked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I tried putting a comment below the author's post but I was unable to. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. "Find partial matches" is already checkmarked.